# Grub not booting Debian without GPU attached

Tags: debian, boot, grub, gpu, headless

**Summary of the problem:**
I want to boot a up to date Debian Buster (freshly installed in UEFI mode; only installed it to test; did not install any desktop environment or X11 or anything alike) without GPU or any other graphic capable hardware in the system. It seems to be a problem with grub as far as I can tell.
I do run a Xeon 1231v3 on a AsRock Extreme4.

**Details and what I did and know so far:**
I do know that this is not a limitation of the board (or other hardwarerelated issue) for two reasons:

1. I asked AsRock support and they told me a quite similar setup to mine does work without graphics card.
2. Windows 10 boots flawlessly on the same machine without any changes in config or setup. I saw this via the Debug Codes on the board (boots to Code AA as expected) and it does play sound when configured to do so and the network gets started properly (tested with a openvpn connection).

What I tested so far:

1. Debian with GPU (with or without screen does not make any difference here): Booting the machine with GPU works flawless. I get an AA on the diagnostics Display and Linux behaves totally as expected. I can SSH into the machine.
2. Windows 10: Booting with or without GPU works both fine. Diagnostics Display shows AA after a couple of seconds and Windows behaves exactly the same.
3. Debian with removed GPU after successful boot: I removed the GPU (dedicated PCIe GPU) after the machine went up. No Problem, everything as expected. Ran for 3 weeks without any issues. Reboot does not work for obvious reasons:
4. Debian without GPU: It stops before the Kernel or initramfs gets loaded. Errorcode is Ad on the onboard diagnostics display.
   I checked what happens at this Errorcode with GPU: You see the grub menu. I paused there to be sure and the diagnostics stayed at Ad until I choose the entry and booted the OS.
   I did setup dropbear. With GPU attached it works fine to decrypt /. Without GPU the machine does not get in the network, which to me confirms, that this is a grub issue.
   *That might be important, but I am not sure how to graps that: Even keyboard input is ignored at this Ad stage: I press CTRL+ALT+DEL commonly a machine in grub menu would restart. It does not. So there is no reaction an keyboard input with grub/debian at this point.*

This leaves two options as far as I can tell:
Either Grub needs a GPU to work or the selected grub entry does need a GPU to boot. Both seems weird to me. I presume I am missing something here in either the config of grub or debian - but I honestly thought that booting a headless linux machine should be no problem at all.
[I did not believe the fact, that just Windows did what Debian would not do - that has not happened to me since ~2008 which is the year I started with linux ;-) But since this is my first attempt at actually running something without GPU or any other graphics output unit I might be missing something.

NOT WORKING without GPU but flawlessly booting with GPU /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodset"
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
```

I tried
'console' as GRUB_TERMINAL
various CMDLINE inputs 'quiet' ''; none had any effect on the problem - same Ad diagnostics output and behaviour.

The System is quite clean and actually does not run any graphicsrelated stuff afaict :

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```

gives me only

```
apparmor.service
autovt@.service
console-setup.service
cron.service
dbus-org.freedesktop.timesync1.service
getty@.service
keyboard-setup.service
networking.service
rsyslog.service
ssh.service
sshd.service
syslog.service
systemd-timesyncd.service
remote-fs.target
apt-daily-upgrade.timer
apt-daily.timer
logrotate.timer
man-db.timer
```

I read a lot of docs for grub, but I do not get what exactly the issue might be. I started to think: Hardware can't do it. But with windows booting without any issue, that just is not a possible explanation for why it is not working.
I tried playing around with grub.cfg (e.g. commenting the video related options out), but had no change of results at all. The default cfg entry (that has the above behaviour) looks like that:

```
[...]
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
        set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuen$
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt2 -$
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root efac4a91-d7a7-43c2-b27a-db5f9ac1c2f2
    fi
    echo    'Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 wird geladen …'
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.19.0-9-amd64 root=UUID=38f85418-3071-44d7-b027-b1965060d07a ro no$
    echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
    initrd  /initrd.img-4.19.0-9-amd64
}
[...]
```

**So the question is:**
How do I get grub to boot Debian Buster without a GPU (and more importantly why is it not booting?!) ? Any help on how to further debug this and get it done is appreciated!

**supplemental edit**

I tested installing debian headless: Started normal installer and removed the GPU after ssh was enabled, so no GPU attached, when anything gets actually installed and configured. Results are the same - does not boot beyond errorcode Ad either.

And forgot to mention: I set multi-user.target via systemd.

**supplemental 01**

Just tested Ubuntu Server (LTS 20.04). Same errorcode and no boot beyond grub without GPU.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I’m also trying to boot a Debian 11 system without a GPU, and not having any luck with it. I’m using an AsRock board (B550 Phantom Gaming-ITX/ax) as well, and I read online that recent AsRock boards should boot without a GPU, so I’m thinking that the problem might be with Debian/GRUB configuration… I used the netinstall ISO when installing the OS and didn’t install any desktop environments.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. So the above is basically still all I can offer. As far as I know the Board works headless (see Windows 10 Booting mentioned above). I concur that it seems to be some Grub/Debian config issue that I was/am not able to figure out. Still interested in the solution so ;-)

Comment: I came here after hours of Googling for the same problem. I'm using an HP EliteDesk Mini G1, and it exhibits the same problem when a monitor is not attached. 

It would seem that without a monitor, this model disables the onboard Intel GPU/Graphics. 

I tried Ubuntu 22.04, and fortunately using `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` fixes this.

For anyone still searching for a solution in 2022, the best answer seems to be "switch to Ubuntu 22.04" and modify GRUB_TERMINAL.

Happy to add this as an answer if the OP considers it useful?

Answer (score 1):

Read the following line 3x times:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodset"
```

... and find the typing error ...

Then, add the missing `e` to `nomodset`, to change it to `nomodeset`.